# Changing the green check when dragging in jstree

Tags: icons, jstree

I am curious if there is a way to programmatically change the green check icon that appears when you drag a jstree node. I haven't seen anything regarding this in jstrees API.

What I have is 2 jstrees. I want the green check and red X to be used when I drag and drop internally. When a node is dragged across trees I want a different icon to appear instead of the green check.

Thanks,
LL

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am interested where the icon comes from so I can change it.

Comment: You can go in and change the PNG it takes images from (one with multiple images and different background image positions used). This is what I'll be doing for my own issue here. For your own issue you could programmatically change the image/style/stylesheet from there. probably.

Answer (score 1):

Change the style of `jstree` like this:

```
#jstree-dnd .jstree-er{ background-image: none !important;}
#jstree-dnd .jstree-er:before{content: "\f05e" !important;font-family: FontAwesome !important; color: #a32020 !important;}
```